# call a variable in a static function to another static function from same class in php

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, call

I have a class with a couple of static functions. One of my functions build a variable and I want to use that variable in another static function.

How can I call that variable?

```
class MyClass{
    public static function show_preprice_value_column( $column, $post_id ) {
        if ( $column == 'product_preprice' ) {
            $product_preprice = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_preprice', true );
            if ( intval( $product_preprice ) > 0 ) {
                echo $product_preprice;
            }
        }
    }

    public static function show_off_value_column( $column, $post_id ) {
        if ( $column == 'product_off' ) {
            var_dump((int)self::show_preprice_value_column());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which variable are you trying to use where?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz   I want to use $product_preprice in show_off_value_column function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
<?php
class MyClass
{

    private static $var;

    public static function funcA()
    {
        self::$var = "a";
    }

    public static function funcB()
    {
        self::$var = "b";
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to use a variable in funcB()

Comment: Add: private static $product_preprice; to the top of your class and call the variable like so: self::$product_preprice

Comment: You can't transfer a variable declared in funcA() to funcB(), but you can use class members to share the variable, like I just did above.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code :

```
class Test {
    public static function test1(){
        return 12;
    }

    public static function test2(){
        $var = self::test1();
        echo $var;
        echo "\n".gettype($var);
    }
} 

Test::test2();
```

And get this as result:

```
12
integer
```

So you need to use `return` after your `echo` to communicate the value